# SVG animation translate bug in IOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, html, svg

I am animating an SVG, to translate a logo when a button is clicked, and to translate it back when another button is clicked.
This works smoothly on all devices other than IOS devices, ipad and iphone (no matter which browser).
On ios the logo will move up once, then won't move up again once it's come back down.
See this example
www.saminaraza.com/fpd/fpd.html

Is there a known issue?
Is there an issue with the code, or will I have to come up with a workaround?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, the trick is reboot the timing in the root SVG animation, by root I mean the svg where the path or shape and his animation lives:

```js
var icon = document.getElementById("button"),
    buttonText = document.getElementById("button-text");




var animationToHome = document.getElementById("morph-to-home");
var animationToFire = document.getElementById("morph-to-fire");
var variconMorphID = document.getElementById("navbar-icon-hot");


button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  
  if (button.classList.contains("saved")) {
    button.classList.remove("saved");
    animationToFire.beginElement();
    buttonText.innerHTML = "Save";
  } else {
    button.classList.add("saved");
    
    variconMorphID.pauseAnimations();
    variconMorphID.setCurrentTime(0);
    variconMorphID.unpauseAnimations();
    
    animationToHome.beginElement();
    buttonText.innerHTML = "Saved!";
  }
  
}, false);
```

```css
button {
  border: 0;
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px 30px 12px;
  outline: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: left;
}
button:hover, button:active {
  background: #dedede;
}
button svg {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
button span {
  font-size: 22px;
  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
  color: white;
}
body {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<button id="button">
  
  <svg class="navbar-icon-svg navbar-icon-hot" id="navbar-icon-hot" version="1.1" id="fire" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 50 50" style="enable-background:new 0 0 50 50;" xml:space="preserve">
   <path class="navbar-icon-morph-svg" d="M13,17.7c2.5,0.7,5.6,3.9,4.7,12.5c5.6-6.3-7-20.6,8.4-30.2c-3.8,7.7-1.5,16.7,5.1,23.7 c-0.2-5,2.4-8.1,6.1-10.5c-1,3.1-1.2,5.9-0.4,9.4c0.9,4,3,6,3.7,12.1c0.5,4.7-0.6,11.8-9.7,14.3c5.2-4.3-1.5-9.5-0.9-13.5 c-1.3,1.8-1.3,4-1,6.1c-4.4-3.9,2.7-9.5-3.7-14.4c1.5,4.6-0.1,8-3.4,10.7c-0.2-1.6-0.7-3.7-2.4-4.3c1.4,6-5.6,11.5,2,16.5 C15,48.3,9.3,44.7,9.3,37.1C9.3,29.7,16.4,24.4,13,17.7z">
    <animate id="morph-to-home" attributeName="d" begin="indefinite" dur=".2s" fill="freeze" keyTimes="0; 0.15; 0.3; 0.45; 0.6; 0.75; 0.9; 1" to="M3,14.9c4-2.9,8.7-6,11.5-7.9c5-3.3,7.2-4.7,10.5-6.9c5.5,3.6,5.5,3.6,10.4,6.9c4.1,2.7,6.3,4.1,11.6,7.6 c0,5.7,0,7.9,0,11.5c0,3.8,0,3.1,0,9.3c0,4.6,0,5.7,0,14.5c-2.8,0-2,0-4,0c0-11,0-26,0-33.2c-4.8-3.1-11-7.2-18-11.9 c-7.4,4.9-14.4,9.5-18,11.9C6.9,23.9,7.1,39,7,50c0,0-2,0-4,0c0-11.8,0-16.3,0-23.8C3,18.8,3,22.2,3,14.9z" />
    <animate id="morph-to-fire" attributeName="d" begin="indefinite" dur=".2s" fill="freeze" to="M13,17.7c2.5,0.7,5.6,3.9,4.7,12.5c5.6-6.3-7-20.6,8.4-30.2c-3.8,7.7-1.5,16.7,5.1,23.7 c-0.2-5,2.4-8.1,6.1-10.5c-1,3.1-1.2,5.9-0.4,9.4c0.9,4,3,6,3.7,12.1c0.5,4.7-0.6,11.8-9.7,14.3c5.2-4.3-1.5-9.5-0.9-13.5 c-1.3,1.8-1.3,4-1,6.1c-4.4-3.9,2.7-9.5-3.7-14.4c1.5,4.6-0.1,8-3.4,10.7c-0.2-1.6-0.7-3.7-2.4-4.3c1.4,6-5.6,11.5,2,16.5 C15,48.3,9.3,44.7,9.3,37.1C9.3,29.7,16.4,24.4,13,17.7z" />
    <animate id="morph-to-home-fast" attributeName="d" begin="indefinite" dur="0.01s" fill="freeze" to="M3,14.9c4-2.9,8.7-6,11.5-7.9c5-3.3,7.2-4.7,10.5-6.9c5.5,3.6,5.5,3.6,10.4,6.9c4.1,2.7,6.3,4.1,11.6,7.6 c0,5.7,0,7.9,0,11.5c0,3.8,0,3.1,0,9.3c0,4.6,0,5.7,0,14.5c-2.8,0-2,0-4,0c0-11,0-26,0-33.2c-4.8-3.1-11-7.2-18-11.9 c-7.4,4.9-14.4,9.5-18,11.9C6.9,23.9,7.1,39,7,50c0,0-2,0-4,0c0-11.8,0-16.3,0-23.8C3,18.8,3,22.2,3,14.9z" />
   </path>
  
  <span id="button-text">Save</span>
  
</button>
```

Here I have a link where you can see it working, works perfect in IOS Safari!!!!

http://codepen.io/jesuscmd/pen/wWBEgR

Answer (score 0):

From a little further research it would seem that an element should only have one animateTransform tag.

In have two, mobile devices were overwriting the first with the second once the first animation was complete.

I've fixed the issue by using snap svg, which I would've liked to avoid since it's such a small instance.

I couldn't figure a way to apply animateTransforms as pure javascript functions.

Comment: I might have the same problem.  What do you mean you fixed it with snap svg?
My fiddle (view in safari vs chrome):
http://jsfiddle.net/20wzj8fk/1/

Comment: Hi sorry for the late response, what I meant was that rather than using core svg transforms I used this library [Snap SVG](http://snapsvg.io/) for animating, which seemed to make everything much more crossbrowser compatible!